# Why is it giving count 1 for each string value?

Tags: java, arrays, string

Below is the code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = scn.nextLine();
        String[] arr = str.split(" ");
        for(int i =0; i<arr.length; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for(int j =0; j<arr.length; j++)
            {
                if(arr[i] == arr[j])
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.print(count + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

How can I count each value of a repeated word in a string?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing comparison with `==` while you should do comparison of strings with `.equals()` or with `Objects.equal()` method. The `==` does memory comparison in string pool and not content comparison.

I have changed your program:

```
class MyClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Set<String> visited = new HashSet<>();
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scn.nextLine();
    String[] arr = str.split(" ");
    for (int loop = 0; loop < arr.length; loop++) {
      int count = 0;
      for (int j = loop; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[loop].equals(arr[j])) {
          count++;
        }
      }
      if (!visited.contains(arr[loop])) {
        System.out.print(arr[loop] + " occured : " + count + " times.\n");
        visited.add(arr[loop]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The program outputs better and handles duplication as well now

OUTPUT:

```
hi hi hi
hi occured : 3 times.
```

```
hi how are you? hi
hi occured : 2 times.
how occured : 1 times.
are occured : 1 times.
you? occured : 1 times.
```